# Name of a theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading Underwood Dudley's Elementary Number Theory (2nd Ed), pg 156 it says:

Theorem. Let
$$F(x,y) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}y+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}y^2+\cdots+a_0y^n,$$
and suppose that $F(x,1)=0$ has no repeated roots. Then the equation
$$F(x,y)=c,$$
where $c$ is an integer, has only finitely many solutions if $n\ge 3$.

Is there a name for this theorem?

Comment: Looks like Faltings' theorem under a different guise: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faltings%27s_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula

Comment: No wait, sorry, those would be integral solutions. I don't see how real solutions are ruled out. I'd wait for other posters

Comment: It's a number theory book. Of course only integer solutions are of interest.

Comment: Yes, I suppose solutions in local fields will have to wait for 'non-elementary number theory'

Comment: @bounceback It's actually the other way around: finding all integer/rational solutions is highly non-elementary, and finding all solutions in local fields is usually quite elementary.

Comment: Indeed, but to understand the definitions of local fields goes well beyond the content of any course in elementary number theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an immediate corollary of Thue's theorem,
see [this text](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eevertse/dio2011-diophantine.pdf), section 3.